Why does subsequent .NET Core application consume more memory?
I have a .NET Core 3.1 application running in Docker Windows Containers on a Windows Server 2022 machine.
I noticed that each subsequent application instance consumes more memory than the previous instance, and it grows with each new application instance:

Why does this happen? Why does the memory consumed not stay equal with each instance?
Please advice

You should update your app ASAP, .NET Core 3.1 is out of support as of December 13, 2022.
